# Custom Marker Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

How would I implement a custom overlay similar to the Wikipedia Layer of Google Maps on Android?

It seems they are overlaying markers dynamically based on X/Y/Zoom, only showing smaller wiki entries as the user zooms in. I know I can overlay an image with a UrlTileProvider/GroundOverlay, but I don't see an obvious way to include custom data/markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you would have to have a database with all entries with assigned lat/lng and importance and a webservice which is called with current zoom level and camera position. Of course if you don't have as many entries as on wikipedia, you can keep it in local db and filter locally.

Using `Markers` seems to be the way to go.